# How to have gcc warn about conversions from uint32_t to uint64_t?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-warnings

Let's take the following simple example:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>

using ::std::vector;
using ::std::uint64_t;
using ::std::uint32_t;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    vector<uint64_t> v;

    uint32_t i = 1;

    v.push_back(i);

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it with:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wconversion -Wpedantic a.cpp
```

I don't get any conversion error. However, I want gcc to warn me because the types `uint64_t` and `uint32_t` don't perfectly match. I undertand that a `uint32_t` fits into a `uint64_t`, but it still some code smell to me. (I would like gcc to force me to cast it)

Is there a way to have gcc warn about that?

Comment: `uint32_t` can be converted to `uint64_t` without any data loss at all - why would the compiler warn you about it?

Comment: Because it smells. It is an implicit conversion.

Comment: `uint32_t i = 1;` is an implicit conversion as well. C++ does it all the time. There's nothing wrong with it unless there's the chance of data loss.

Comment: I would say that the initialization from a constant is not the same category as the runtime conversion of a type to another type.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt `1` is of type `int`.

Comment: That was never questioned, @JonathanPotter. What is your point?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt that the example I gave to the OP was an implicit conversion (from `int` to `uint32_t`). What is your point?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, there is no difference between a compile time known value `int` being converted to `uint32_t` and a value that is only known at run time

Comment: The C++ standard doesn't distinguish between run-time and compile-time.

Comment: I was referring to your claim that "There's nothing wrong with [an implicit conversion] unless there's the chance of data loss.", @JonathanPotter, which is something I disagree with. There are for example performance considerations that do make a difference. In the case of an initialization from an integer literal, I don't fear any performance impact though, which is why it's a different category of implicit conversions than the `push_back()` call.

Comment: Implicit conversions are generally *better* than explicit conversions (casts), because the language does a pretty good job of deciding what conversion is needed. If you write `v.push_back(static_cast<uint64_t>(i));`, you have to ensure that you use the correct type; if you don't, you won't get a warning. On the other hand, a conversion (either explicit or implicit) is often a sign that the value being converted should have been of the target type in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with that conversion because the a `uint32_t` being converted to a `uint64_t` will not alter the value: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wconversion-499

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        std::uint32_t i = 1;
        std::uint64_t j = 1;

        // warning: conversion to 'uint32_t {aka unsigned int}' from 'uint64_t {aka long long unsigned int}' may alter its value
        // i = j;

        // No problem here
        j = i;

        // Use j to avoid an error
        std::cout << j << std::endl;

        return 0;
}
```

There won't be a compiler flag for `j = i;` because there is nothing wrong with it, the "smell" is just your preference

Answer (score 1):

`uint64_t` have 64 bits, `uint32_t` have only 32 bits. When `uint32` change into `uint64`, it only add `0` in high 32 bits, the data is unchanged. So there is no any warning needed for a compiler. But when `uint64_t` change into `uint32_t`, the compiler would give a warning, because the data maybe be changed. So the warning you want could not get.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this, but with C++11 UDLs you can write your own set of classes to be used instead of the normal integers, so you can provide whatever semantics you want.

It's probably quite painful for integers, I have only done it for string literals.